# For a stationary and ergodic discrete stochastic process $\{X[n]\}_t$, $X[n]$'s are Independent and identically distributed?

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

I can find some materials that say

"if $X[n]$'s are independent and identically distributed (IID), then a random process $\{X[n]\}_n$ is an ergodic process."

I think the converse does not hold (just guess...) That is, "even if a random process $\{X[n]\}_n$ is an ergodic process, $X[n]$'s may be non-IID."

What if a random process $\{X[n]\}_n$ is of ergodic as well as stationary? That is, "if a discrete stochastic process $\{X[n]\}_t$ is stationary and ergodic, then $X[n]$'s are IID?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. Discrete Markov chains are a popular example: these are often stationary and ergodic, but not iid.

You can try to construct one yourself.

Comment: If so, for given $\{Y[n]\}_n$ that is stationary and ergodic, can I say $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log_2 (1+|Y[n]|^2 p(Y[n])) = \mathbb{E}(\log_2 (1+|Y|^2 p(Y)))$ even if $Y[n]$'s are not iid?

Comment: Yes, if this expectation exists.

Comment: Actually, I am sure that the equality will be based on the Ergodic Theory. However, understanding how it comes from is so challenging for me who is not majoring in Math. Do you know any papers that proves $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f(Y[n]) = \mathbb{E}[f(Y[n])]$ without using deep mathematical terminology, e.g., measure-preserving transformation? Actually, $\sigma$-algebra, something-space, transformation, ... are so challenging notions for me who only studied engineering math and engineering-perspective random signal process.

Comment: Are you looking for a rigorous proof or do you want intuition?

Comment: I am looking for both!! Proof for non-mathematicians is very good. (The followings are not about this question.... Why do the mathematicians use $\mathbb{E}X$ instead of $\mathbb{E}(X)$ or $\mathbb{E}[X]$? Likewise $T^nX$ instead of $T^n(X)$. Is it the notation rule of topology math?)

Comment: Ergodicity means intuitively that sequence will cover the whole space. The intuition for the ergodic theorem is then similar to the intuition for the law of large numbers (if you are familiar with it). Sadly, I'm personally not aware of any elementary proofs of ergodic theorems that do not use any measure theory (or probability theory). Concerning the last question: I think it's a mix of convention, habit and wanting to save time and space. Cutting down on the parentheses can also help make thing easier to read sometimes.

Comment: Yes, the law of large numbers are very familiar. Hahaha. Anyway, your comments are more valuable than anything else. I think I really need to study measure theory after finding the easiest measure theory textbook. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127686/discussion-between-danny-kim-and-dasherman).